# Error running Bluemix bluelist-push android sample

Tags: android, node.js, ibm-cloud

I am executing the [bluelist-push](https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/bluelist-push/overview) demo following this tutorial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-push-app/index.html

Everything is working fine except that the other devices are not getting notified if list changes in one device.

Following is the error in logcat:

> 09-01 18:39:10.415  17896-18359/com.ibm.bluelist I/MainActivity﹕ Response Body: Cannot POST /eta-chat/v1/apps/3ab78df7-3b35-402e-b45e-2fccf39ad3bc/notifyOtherDevices
>
> 09-01 18:39:10.416  17896-18359/com.ibm.bluelist I/MainActivity﹕
>   Response Status from notifyOtherDevices: 404

My app is running at: http://eta-chat.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Looks like it can't find the other devices  (404) error. Can you share the code you are using for push notifications?

Comment: yes, please share your Node code. I think your local Android app cannot find the notifyOtherDevices method within your Node server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is 404ing when attempting to send the POST request to your Node.js app. Most likely because the endpoint does not exist.

Please ensure you have configured your app.js to include your appID and appRoute along with the notifyOtherDevices endpoint implementation.

Once you have confirmed the above, `cf push` the app to your Bluemix runtime and you should not run into this problem anymore.

Lastly make sure you have registered a device to the Push service. Attempting to notify an empty list of devices may cause a 404 as well.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I checked again, my Node.js code was not updated properly. I got the clue from application logs using command                              cf logs APP_NAME --recent                                                                     from command-line.